# Example of a sample space where probability measure is not well-defined.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In my textbook for Introduction to Probability, there is the following extract on the topic of sigma algebras:

> If Ω is finite or countable then we can take F to be the power set
>   P(Ω) of Ω, that is the set of all subsets of Ω. However, if Ω is
>   uncountable, then taking P(Ω) for F could cause problems when trying
>   to measure the likeliness, or probability, of events, so in that case
>   we usually choose F to be a subset of P(Ω).

This seems a bit unclear to me as I'm new to the set-theoretic approach to probability so I was hoping I could get a concrete example of a sample space where we can't define probability measure and so have to consider a measurable subset.

Comment: Have you ever heard about the Banach-Tarski paradox?

Comment: I have. I was expecting the sort of issues you come into to be a bit more 'vanilla' but that certainly sounds like a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your book refers to is the existance of non-measurable sets. The existance of non measurable sets is really non-trivial and to give rigorous proof for their existance you have to develop measure theory to some extent.The most basic such set is called the Vitaly set (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set)).

Coming from another directions, the Banach Tarski Paradox(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox)) states that you can partition the solid 3-d sphere into 5 pieces and rearrange them to get two balls identical to the first one ! If this 5 pieces had a logical volume (which is exactly the measure of probability to pick them, in a sense) then by moving them in space you couldn't take something of double the volume ! Therefore the mustn't have a well defined notion of volume!

This might seem like handwaving but there is a deeper reason. It has been proven that to create such *bad* sets you need to use the **Axiom of choise**, therefore you can show that they exists but you can't really describe what they are made of!